# Powershell - Sorting table by username and Time Created

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to sort a csv table by username and then sort the time created column for each of those users?

I would like to see if I could sort the time created column from most recent back.

I am working on a script to look at the last logon of each user in the security event logs.

I can sort it by name but the time written is not in any order.

My next goal would be to just show that latest time created entry for one user and not the rest of the entries.

```
$time = (Get-Date) – (New-TimeSpan -Day 30)
$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME

#Delete any previously created files
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\PowerShellScripts\LastLogon\Results" -Recurse |
Where-Object CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-0) | Remove-Item -        
ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$hastable = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable 
@{Logname='Security';ID=4624;starttime=$time} -ComputerName $ComputerName |

? {($_.Properties[8].Value -eq '10' ) -and 
($_.Properties[5].Value -ne 'SYSTEM' ) -and
( $_.Properties[5].Value -ne 'Agvadmin' ) -and
( $_.Properties[5].Value -ne 'Agvance' ) -and
( $_.Properties[5].Value -ne 'ssi1' ) -and
( $_.Properties[5].Value -ne 'ssi2' ) -and
( $_.Properties[5].Value -ne 'ssi3' ) -and
( $_.Properties[5].Value -notmatch 'DWM' ) -and
( $_.Properties[5].Value -notmatch 'Default' ) -and
( $_.Properties[5].Value -notmatch 'TS6' ) -and
( $_.Properties[5].Value -notmatch 'DC1' ) -and
( $_.Properties[5].Value -notmatch 'DC1' ) -and
( $_.Properties[5].Value -notmatch 'SQLTELEMETRY' ) -and
( $_.Properties[5].Value -notmatch 'MSSQL' ) -and
( $_.Properties[5].Value -notmatch "$env:COMPUTERNAME" ) -and
( $_.Properties[5].Value -ne 'PANKAHLERSERVER$' ) -and
( $_.Properties[5].Value -ne 'GREKAHLERSRVR$' ) -and
( $_.Properties[5].Value -ne 'DIEKAHLERSERVER$' ) -and
( $_.Properties[5].Value -ne 'ANONYMOUS LOGON' ) -and
( $_.Properties[5].Value -ne 'LOCAL SERVICE' ) -and
( $_.Properties[5].Value -ne 'NETWORK SERVICE' ) -and
( $_.Properties[5].Value -ne 'ssiadmin' ) -and
( $_.Properties[5].Value -ne 'Administrator') 

 } |

select @{N='User';E={$_.Properties[5].Value}} , @{N='TimeCreated';E=
{$_.TimeCreated}} , @{l="Logon Type";e={$_.Properties[8].Value}} 



$hastable.GetEnumerator()| Sort -Property User |

Export-Csv C:\PowerShellScripts\Lastlogon\Results\LastLogon.csv -
NoTypeInformation


#The user count is created here
$number = (Import-Csv C:\PowerShellScripts\Lastlogon\Results\LastLogon.csv | 
measure | % { $_.Count})

#The file is renamed to include computername, date, and user count
rename-item -path C:\PowerShellScripts\Lastlogon\Results\LastLogon.csv -
NewName 
C:\PowerShellScripts\Lastlogon\Results\LastLogon-$ComputerName-$CurrentDate-
UserCount-$number.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can sort by multiple properties by passing a comma delimited list of properties you want to sort by.

You can even use an expression to sort the first property with Ascending while the second is Descending or vice-versa.

```
$list | sort Age,Weight 

# Using expression 
$list | sort Age, @{'e'={$_.Weight};a=1} -Descending
```

Complete example:

```
$list = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.Generic.List[Object]

$Properties = @('Age','Weight','Number','Tag')
For ($i=0;$i -le 1000;$i++) {
    $item = New-Object psobject
    foreach ($P in $Properties) {
        Add-Member -InputObject $item -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $p -value (Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 10)
    }
$list.Add($item)
}

$list | sort Age,Weight 

# Using expression 
$list | sort Age, @{'e'={$_.Weight};a=1} -Descending
```

I'm not sure I understood your "next part goal" but it seems to me that you might just want to do a `Select -First 1`

Comment: Thank you, I will try that and see if that will work.  That would make sense if I did the select -first but I would probably have to group them together by name and choose the first entry of each group.